# How to web scrape a span class tag from Rotten tomatoes (audience score tag)

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rotten-tomatoes

I'm new to python and I have been trying to web scrape the audience score from a movie page.
79%

However it always return back empty.

```
<div class="score-board-wrap">
      <slot name="title"></slot>
      <div class="info-container">
        <span id="rating">R</span>
        <slot name="info"></slot>
      </div>
      <div class="scores-container">
        <div class="tomatometer-container" data-qa="tomatometer-container">
          <div tabindex="0">
            <score-icon-critic alignment="right" size="medium" data-qa="score-icon-critic" state="certified_fresh" percentage="98"></score-icon-critic>
          </div>
          <span class="score-type">Tomatometer</span>
          <slot name="critics-count"></slot>
        </div>
        <div class="audience-container" data-qa="audience-score-container">
          <div tabindex="0">
            <score-icon-audience alignment="left" size="medium" skeleton="chip" data-qa="score-icon-audience" state="upright" percentage="79"></score-icon-audience>
          </div>
          <span class="score-type">Audience Score</span>
          <slot name="audience-count"></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The closest I got was when I entered x=soup.select('score-board'), I get a string back with text, but I cant pass anything out of it.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    
    url= 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/one_night_in_miami'
    page=requests.get(url)
    soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    x=soup.select('score-board')
    x
    
    Output:
    
    [<score-board audiencescore="79" audiencestate="upright" class="scoreboard" data-qa="score-panel" rating="R" skeleton="panel" tomatometerscore="98" tomatometerstate="certified-fresh">
     <h1 class="scoreboard__title" data-qa="score-panel-movie-title" slot="title">One Night in Miami</h1>
     <p class="scoreboard__info" slot="info">2020, Drama, 1h 50m</p>
     <a class="scoreboard__link scoreboard__link--tomatometer" data-qa="tomatometer-review-count" href="/m/one_night_in_miami/reviews?intcmp=rt-scorecard_tomatometer-reviews" slot="critics-count">330 Reviews</a>
     <a class="scoreboard__link scoreboard__link--audience" data-qa="audience-rating-count" href="/m/one_night_in_miami/reviews?type=user&amp;intcmp=rt-scorecard_audience-score-reviews" slot="audience-count">1,000+ Ratings</a>
     </score-board>]


#first_mscore = soup.find('span', class_ = 'percentage')
#print(first_mscore)

#mov=soup.find('span',{'class':'audience-score'})
```

All I need is the audience score **scraped**. Any help will be deeply appreciated. TIA!

Answer (score 0):

You can find value of attribute by passing into tag and also you can try with `.get` method

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url= 'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/one_night_in_miami'
page=requests.get(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
per=soup.find("score-board")['audiencescore']
print(per)
```

**Output:**

```
79
```

**Method 2:**

```
soup.find("score-board").get("audiencescore")
```

Comment: This method worked too.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there.

Just extract the attribute `audiencescore` from `x[0]`. *Since `select` returns a list, you need to select the first item and then extract the attribute.*

> `x[0]['audiencescore']`

#### Using `select`:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
x = soup.select('score-board')

print(x[0]['audiencescore'])
```

#### Using `select_one`:

```
x = soup.select_one('score-board')['audiencescore']
```

Output

```
79
```

Comment: Thank you!! this method also worked. Really appreciate it!